# Should I try not to save Firebase Auth on LocalStorage

Tags: firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

While preparing my web app for production I am noticing that Firebase saves a lot of users's data once they sign up/register to my app and these data is save on localStorage.

What is my concern is auto generated uid, I don't want users to be able to know their own uid and I don't want that piece of data to be saved on localStorage.

So I have two questions, should I concern about this ? since I do not have so much experience with authentication in general and I am afraid someone could do something...

Is there any way to remove the localStorage and firebase auth to work correctly ?

Cheers

Comment: There's no risk giving users access to uid. Uids are simply random generated strings and there's nothing much users can do with it. Unless you use those uids in your database and this database is public.

Comment: @RosárioPereiraFernandes Hello, sorry to grab this up again, Im developing a SSR App so i save the Auth Token saved in the Cookies, i also save user related data in the Firestore with the uid as the Document Key, is there any possiblity that there will be security flaws when the User modifies the UID even if i have proper Firestore security rules? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Do not rely on `uid` to identify an authenticated user. You should only use the ID token JWT for current user, by calling `currentUser.getIdToken()` and if you are using your own backend server, verify the ID token using the Firebase Admin SDKs by calling `verifyIdToken`. Learn more about ID tokens: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Answer (score 0):

No , Because firebase auth is part of authentication with server database. if your trying to do like this then your application will not be able to signup or login.